# How to use a normal map for light effects with an AnimatedSrpite?

Tags: animation, lighting, godot

I am trying to add light effects with normal map on an AnimatedSprite. I was following that [tutorial](https://www.gdquest.com/tutorial/godot/2d/lighting-with-normal-maps/) but with no success.

I am using a `Ligth2D`, this sprite sheet:

[image]

and have created a shader on Material to apply the normal map with this code:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform sampler2D normal_map;

void fragment(){
    NORMAL = 2.0 * texture(normal_map, UV).rgb - 1.0;
}
```

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

One can observe a light reflection on the left upper of the hourglass, but the light is neither smooth nor consistant.

NB: I have made the spirte sheet myself, feel free to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was from the fact that I was using a single sprite normal map with a sprite sheet:

When using this, everything works just fine:

[image]